# High performance web (-services) applications

Tags: performance, web-applications, scalability

I'd like to become a guru in high performance (100k and more views/requests) web & web-services applications.
What technologies/patterns/skills do you reccomend to look at?
Basically, I have good skills at ASP.NET/.NET based web development, but I'd like to know how big things are built (on any platform, not depending on .net technology stack).

Thank you.

Comment: Check out [High Scalability blog](http://highscalability.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For web/webservices the most common thing would be the data retrieval part
so you would need to concentrate first on sql performance tuning (indexes, sp fine tuning etc)

For web sites you would need to look @ things like js minimize, server side rendering etc

In addition learning how to read performance counters, fiddler output will help point to probable performance bottlenecks

Comment: I'm familiar with all these things you've mentioned.
I'll try to reformulate the question. Thanks

Comment: just 1 more:
you can read thru this book High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers
 
High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers



http://astore.amazon.com/possiboutpos-20/detail/0596529309

this is specific to websites

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance with Web services [consuming and producing] you might want to research alternative web service packages and replacing the XML serialization/deserialization bits. XML serial/de is one of the slowest most painful processes surrounding the delivery of data. [at least when it comes to processing].

Other than: look for the bottle necks in the order of the largest, to the smallest.